# Javascript iteration over hash error

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, hash

I'm making a mistake iterating over a hash but I'm not sure of the error...

In the controller, I have a hash, passed to Gon, that looks like this:

```
@images = {
   "titleA" => "12345678"
   "titleB" => "123456789"
   "titleC" => "1234567890"
}
gon.images = @images
```

In the view body, I'm creating a series of div ids based on the image title like this:

```
<% @images.each do |image, key| %>
   <div id="<%= "#{image}" %>">
```

In the view script, I'm trying to use the same kind of loop to call a function (loading a photoset) each time the id with that unique ID is clicked. In other words, when the user clicks the div with the id of "titleA", the photoset "12345678" should be loaded, and so forth.

```
for ( var image in gon.images )
    document.getElementById(image).onclick = function()
    {
       flickr:"set"+gon.images[image]
    }
```

The problem I'm having now, is that whenever I click any of the divs, regardless if it's ID per the ruby view is "titleA" or "titleB" or "titleC", the only photoset that's called is "12345678". I'm probably getting my loop wrong, but can anyone help?

Thanks!

Note: the code for flickr and everything is based on pre-existing functions, and everything works fine, except for the fact that only the photoset for one key is ever returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JavaScript has only function scope (not block scope), you'd have to wrap the function in a new function (a closure), capturing the reference to `image` permanently:

```
for (var image in gon.images) {
    document.getElementById(image).onclick = (function(image) {
      return function() {
        // flickr:"set"+gon.images[image]
      }
    })(image);
}
```

The `image` variable, within each of your anonymous functions, is bound to the same variable outside of the function.  Therefore, at the time the `click` function is executed, since the loop would have completed in its entirety, the value of `image` is the last value computed in the loop.

It boils down to this: **the value of `image` in the click function is bound at the time of execution, and not creation, of the function.**